# How to compare two dates without using Stat?

Tags: awk, date

I'm trying to compare the last date modified of a file to today's date. If the modification date is before today's date then my script will do one thing, if the date matches todays date i need it to do another. Right now my code looks like this:

```
date2= ls -l file | awk '{print $6 $7}'
date1= date +%b%d

if (( $(printf "%(%s)T" "$date1") > $(printf "%(%s)T" "$date2") ))
then
  echo "date1 is after date2"
else
  echo "date1 is not after date2"
fi
```

This code is not working. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Avoid parsing `ls` if possible. If you can't or don't want to use `stat`, you can get modification time of the file with a `date -r file`. You have a number of other bugs in the code as wrong/missing command substitution in the assignment `$()` or space after `=`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have GNU `find` installed, the following line will return the filename if it was last modified earlier than today

```
find yourfile -prune -daystart -mtime +0 -print
```

Answer (score 3):

You can compare file timestamps directly in `bash/zsh/ksh` with the test operator `-nt` (*newer-than*).
You can also use `touch` to set a time on a file, eg `0:00` for midnight
today. So simply:

```
touch -d '0:00' /tmp/midnight
if [ file -nt /tmp/midnight ] ...
```

Comment: dang. I was just gonna say the same thing.

Comment: It worth noticing that `touch` accepts date in mostly free form, human readable format, i.e. `next Thursday` would work as well as ISO 8601 date. For more information see [Date input formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html) section of GNU coreutils documentation.

Answer (score 2):

If on a GNU system, you can use this :

```
#!/bin/bash
last_mod="$(date -r "$1" '+%Y%m%d')"
current="$(date '+%Y%m%d')"

if [ "$last_mod" -eq "$current" ]; then
    ## Do something
elif [ "$last_mod" -gt "$current" ]; then
    ## Do something
else
    ## Do something
fi
```

Insert the file name as first argument to the script.

- `last_mod` will contain the last modification date of the file
- `current` will contain today's date

Answer (score 1):

```
if [[ $(date -d$(date +%D) +%s) -gt  $(date +%s -r file.txt) ]]; then
      echo "Not Today" 
      else echo "Today"
fi
```

This will compare time elapsed since epoch at 00:00 today and modification date since epoch of the file.txt.